# How can I get the version of a bundle installed by Composer in Symfony?

Tags: symfony, controller, composer-php, version

We have multiple vendor bundles (both external and internally written) that are installed into Symfony via Composer. So an example from composer.json of one would be:

```
"repoName/ThisBundle" : "dev-release/1.1.2"
```

So in the controller in Symfony, how could I request the version of "ThisBundle" or "repoName/ThisBundle" to return "dev-release/1.1.2"?

One of the bundles serves a template to all our apps, and in one of the apps I want to display the template version being used.

Comment: You can just parse the lock file

Comment: True, and that's what I was thinking of doing, but that's a lot of effort to get a version number. Seeing as Symfony is a frame work it would be nice to access these details through the frame work.

Answer (score 6):

you just type

```
 composer.phar show
```

Will show all the currently installed packages and their version information.
To see more details, specify the name of the package as well:

```
composer.phar show bundle/bundlename
```

That will show many things, including commit MD5 hash, source URL, license type, etc.

Comment: Perhaps you could update your answer with an example of how to do this from inside a controller?

Comment: Yeh, this seems to be the way to do it via command line, not in a controller (via php).

Comment: $this->container->getParameter('kernel.bundles');

Answer (score 0):

If you have container object available (and it is the case if you're in a controller) then you can get array of the enabled bundles by

```
$this->container->getParameter('kernel.bundles');
```

but remember, just the enabled bundle in the appkernal.php
good luck

Comment: This is great as you can find out if a bundle is installed, however, you can still not get the version of a particular installed bundle, just if it is installed or not. This array would be awesome if it were a multidimensional array where instead of just having the path it had the installed version as well.

Comment: @MicWit i can see a way (a bad way to this) you change your .htaacces file so that it's allow to access the composer.json file and then just use the json_decode function to transform it into an array, and it's done.
but it still a bad way to do things because the web directory should be the only place accesible in public, good luck

Comment: Yeh, not going to do it that way as we would be shot by the security team! Looks like there is no way to do this, may add a feature request to Symfony.